# Querying FIX protocol message files using Apache Drill

Tags: apache, csv, apache-drill

I was able to query FIX messages as a csv using delimiter as '\u0001', but the results had tag=value in each of the columns, like so:

Expected:

```
---------
 8      |
---------
 FIX.4.4|
 FIX.4.4|
 FIX.4.4|
 FIX.4.4|
 FIX.4.4|
---------
```

Actual:

```
-----------
 EXPR$1   |
-----------
 8=FIX.4.4|
 8=FIX.4.4|
 8=FIX.4.4|
 8=FIX.4.4|
 8=FIX.4.4|
-----------
```

How do I query FIX protocol message files using Apache Drill to achieve the above expected result?
Will this need a custom storage format implementation?

Comment: It looks like you would need to create custom storage format.

Answer (score 1):

You can [contribute to Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/docs/apache-drill-contribution-guidelines/) and develop "FIX Protocol" storage format plugin.

Also you can try to parse your string values and extract the result from it by SQL:

```
0: jdbc:drill:> SELECT split(a, '=')[0] as `key`, split(a, '=')[1] as `value` FROM (VALUES('8=FIX.4.4')) t(a);
+------+----------+
| key  |  value   |
+------+----------+
| 8    | FIX.4.4  |
+------+----------+
```